# Difference between Django JSONField and TextField

Tags: json, django

I have to save a JSON string to a Django model and am curious as to which field type I should use. I have seen a `JSONField` used before, but surely a `TextField` will do the exact same job since JSON is a string?

What type of field should I be using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is true to an extent, but with PostgreSQL (now all database backends, see below) at least there is a specific database JSON field type. This means you can query a model based on the contents of that field. From the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield:

```
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
...     'breed': 'labrador',
...     'owner': {
...         'name': 'Bob',
...         'other_pets': [{
...             'name': 'Fishy',
...         }],
...     },
... })
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'breed': 'collie'})

>>> Dog.objects.filter(data__breed='collie')
<QuerySet [<Dog: Meg>]>
```

Additionally, when you do `dog.data`, the field value is automatically converted to its native Python format, in this case a dictionary. With a TextField you'd have to do `data = json.reads(dog.data)` as an explicit step. (I believe this happens in the field type's `from_db_value()` method.)

Update 4 August 2020: from Django 3.1 onwards, JSONField can be used in all supported database backends https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2020/aug/04/django-31-released/

Comment: what is PostgreSQL? Is it another database type and if so, can I still use a JSONField with the default sqlite3 database?

Comment: Yes. Django supports a variety, but the most common is probably Postgres, AKA PostgreSQL. See [Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/) in the docs. JSONField won't work on sqlite3. I haven't tried it, but I guess that it will fail when you try to run migrations.

Comment: as for sqlite3 and JSONField migrations run just fine but adding a model w. JSONField ends in error